# How to use joda time to achieve sql date format and to calculate years

Tags: date, jodatime

I have a mysql DB and the dates are stored in it using the sql format of yyyy-MM-dd
I am using Jcalender for gui to get my customers DOB in java swing.

How do I use it to calculate the age of the person using yearsBetween() in joda time and then convert it to an int.

Please help, a code will be really useful :)

Okay I will post the code which is causing the problem

```
    String dob = "1965-02-03";

    DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.now().toLocalDate().toString());
    DateTime start = new DateTime(dob);

    System.out.println(today);
    System.out.println(dob);

    Years y= Years.yearsBetween(start, today);

     System.out.println(y);
```

why does the y return a value of P485 instead of the correct value?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Additionally, you should store dates *as dates* in the database. What format you happen to see those in when querying them and converting the results to strings is irrelevant.

Comment: I just need help as startup and yes they are stored as dates in the Database, where can I get information about what I want to do, the javadoc for Joda is massive and I cannot find what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SysOut over class *Years* is missing a "*getYears( )*".

The code should be like this:

```
    final String dob = "1965-02-03";

    final DateTime today = LocalTime.now().toDateTimeToday();
    final DateTime start = DateTime.parse(dob);

    System.out.println(today);
    System.out.println(dob);

    final Years y = Years.yearsBetween(start, today);

    System.out.println(y.getYears());
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to convert it to string and trying to parse it to int causing wrong values.